# sylpheed not pulling from gmail accounts where other applications can

Tags: sylpheed

Ubuntu 19.04 / MATE

I have two gmail accounts which I can access for IMAP in Mailspring and Thunderbird.

Sylpheed gives no error through the UI. The sylpheed log has only a debug statement.

```
DEBUG: Name com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar does not exist on the session bus
```

Clicking `Get`, `Get All` has no effect on either account. `Get All checks for new mail` is enabled on both accounts.

General setting : `Get new mail on startup` is enabled. Sylpheed has been restarted.

Both accounts have way way way too much unread mail, but sylpheed is not pulling any of it down.